# "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views. " How to solve this crash in my case?

Tags: java, android, class, android-studio, android-fragments

I have the following problem.

I have a `RewardedVideoListener` in `Class1` and want to make some views `INVISIBLE` in `Class2` as soon as the rewarded video is played.

The problem is that I get following error:

```
2019-10-20 22:13:48.336 13565-13587/com.myapp.nameE/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2
    Process: com.fujigames.memesoundboard, PID: 13565
    android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6855)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:1075)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:5242)
        at android.view.View.invalidateInternal(View.java:13574)
        at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:13538)
        at android.view.View.setFlags(View.java:11447)
        at android.view.View.setVisibility(View.java:8001)
        at com.myapp.name.MainActivity.onRewardedVideoAdRewarded(MainActivity.java:449)
        at com.ironsource.mediationsdk.sdk.ListenersWrapper$7.run(ListenersWrapper.java:198)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at com.ironsource.mediationsdk.sdk.ListenersWrapper$CallbackHandlerThread.run(ListenersWrapper.java:499)
```

Here is the method in `Class1` which is called when the rewarded video just finished:

```
@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdRewarded(Placement placement) {
    Class2 cl2 = new Class2();

    cl2.greyBackgroundcl2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.greyBackgroundcl2);
    cl2.adtextcl2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.adtextcl2);
    cl2.showcl2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.showVideocl2);

    cl2.showcl2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    cl2.greyBackgroundcl2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    cl2.adtextcl2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

And this is `Class2` (A `Fragment`)

```
public class Class2 extends Fragment {

    public Button showcl2;
    public ImageView greyBackgroundcl2;
    public TextView adtextcl2;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab5_layout,container,false);
        mLayout=rootView.findViewById(R.id.tab5);
    }
}
```

I'm pretty new to Android Studio so I tried to fix it on my own but didn't found good answers on Google.

How do I prevent the app from crashing? (It crashes as soon as the rewarded Video ends)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change onRewardedVideoAdRewarded method like this

```
@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdRewarded(Placement placement) {
final Class2 cl2 = new Class2();

cl2.greyBackgroundcl2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.greyBackgroundcl2);
cl2.adtextcl2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.adtextcl2);
cl2.showcl2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.showVideocl2);

MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        cl2.showcl2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        cl2.greyBackgroundcl2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        cl2.adtextcl2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to find the view elements from a `Fragment` (that is `Class2` in your case) which are not inflated yet.

I would like to recommend keeping a `public static boolean` variable in your `Class1` where the reward video is being played and use that as an indicator in your `Class2`. Let us take an example as follows.

```
public static boolean isRewardVideoPlayed = false;

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdRewarded(Placement placement) {
    isRewardVideoPlayed = true;
}
```

Now in the `onCreateView` of your `Class2`, check the value of `isRewardVideoPlayed` and based on the value, set your visibilities of the views.

```
public class Class2 extends Fragment {

    public Button showcl2;
    public ImageView greyBackgroundcl2;
    public TextView adtextcl2;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab5_layout,container,false);
        mLayout=rootView.findViewById(R.id.tab5);

        greyBackgroundcl2 = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.greyBackgroundcl2);
        adtextcl2 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.adtextcl2);
        showcl2 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.showVideocl2);

        if(Class1.isRewardVideoPlayed) {
            showcl2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            greyBackgroundcl2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            adtextcl2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

If both of your `Fragment`s are visible at the same time, you might consider putting the code segment in your `onResume` function so that it takes effect as soon as the reward video is finished playing.

```
@override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if(Class1.isRewardVideoPlayed) {
        showcl2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        greyBackgroundcl2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        adtextcl2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

I hope that helps!